# C# DateTime.Parse method losses nanosecond precision of the timestamp string

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I need to convert an RFC-3339 formatted timestamp (e.g. "2024-01-04T14:30:00.119919872Z") to a unix nanosecond timestamp (e.g. 1704378600119919872). However, the C# DateTime structures maximum precision is only 100 nanoseconds. For example:

```
string timestamp = "2024-01-04T14:30:00.119919872Z";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(timestamp);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("O")); // outputs: 2024-01-04T09:30:00.1199199-05:00
```

So the fractional seconds components of the timestamp get rounded to - 1199199 - the nearest 100 nanoseconds. Apparently, 100 nanoseconds is the DateTime structures precision.

To avoid this loss of precision, I've written my own parsing method, but it's very ugly -

```
public static long ToUnixNanoseconds(string str)
{
    string dateTimeStr = str[..19];
    DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeStr + "Z");
    long unixTimeSeconds = (new DateTimeOffset(utcDateTime)).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
    string fractionalSecondsStr = str[19..(str.Length - 1)];
    decimal fractionalSeconds = decimal.Parse(fractionalSecondsStr);
    long unixNano = (long)((unixTimeSeconds + fractionalSeconds) * 1000000000);
    return unixNano;
}
```

What better ways are there to convert an RFC-3339 timestamp to a unix timestamp with nanosecond precision in C#?

Comment: That is correct. The C# `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` values are measured in `ticks` since "12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.)", where a tick is 100 nanoseconds. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-datetime#overview)

Comment: So is there no support for parsing times with full nanosecond precision? :(

Comment: Check https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime

Comment: I think this is the implementation, though I doubt you'd want to reuse it. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d8c3db7d096da710a3f667d70c36e34c1bf63921/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Globalization/DateTimeParse.cs#L4568

Comment: why would you need a precision smaller than 100 nanoseconds. ?

Comment: @MitchWheat In my case I'm parsing financial market data objects with unix nanosecond timestamps. Rounding off two orders of magnitude of precision will mean that the order that events happen in is not preserved. Things happen very fast in the world of finance.

Comment: @Treker : I'd say that if you are relying on the ordering from sub 100 nanosecond precision, then your design might be broken. For instance: are these events coming from multiple systems? Do they all have atomic clocks?

Comment: The events are trades and quotes which occur at various stock exchanges and are processed and consolidated by entities called SIPs (securities information processors). In the US there are primarily two SIPs - the CTA for NYSE listed stocks and the UTP for NASDAQ listed stocks.

Answer (score 1):

Your parsing method seems okay, if you always expect that same input format and don't want to include a full library just for this one use case (although Noda Time is really good.)

You could do a little tweaking. Here's my approach:

```
public static long ToUnixNanoseconds(ReadOnlySpan<char> timestamp)
{
    var seconds = DateTimeOffset.Parse(timestamp[0..19], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
    var fractionalSeconds = decimal.Parse(timestamp[19..^1], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return (long)((seconds + fractionalSeconds) * 1000000000);
}
```